# std::string memory overwritten?

Tags: c++, stdstring

With this code:

```
std::string create_bc( std::string   current_bk,
                       std::string   local_isin,
                       std::string   local_fininfo,
                       std::string   local_ccy,
                       std::string   local_ric,
                       QSqlDatabase* db)
{
    std::string req;
    req.reserve(1024);

    req = "dbo.create_bsk_constituent @bk_cod=";
    std::cout << req << std::endl;
    req += current_bk;
    std::cout << req << std::endl;
    req += " , @ISIN= ";
    std::cout << req << std::endl;
    req += local_isin;
    std::cout << req << std::endl;
    req += " , @FININFO= ";
    std::cout << req << std::endl;
    req += local_fininfo;
    std::cout << req << std::endl;
    req += " , @dev_cod= ";
    std::cout << req << std::endl;
    req += local_ccy;
    std::cout << req << std::endl;
```

I got this output:

```
dbo.create_bsk_constituent @bk_cod=
dbo.create_bsk_constituent @bk_cod=bk11
dbo.create_bsk_constituent @bk_cod=bk11 , @ISIN=
dbo.create_bsk_constituent @bk_cod=bk11 , @ISIN= EU0009658145
dbo.create_bsk_constituent @bk_cod=bk11 , @ISIN= EU0009658145 , @FININFO=
dbo.create_bsk_constituent @bk_cod=bk11 , @ISIN= EU0009658145 , @FININFO= 22
 , @dev_cod= k_constituent @bk_cod=bk11 , @ISIN= EU0009658145 , @FININFO= 22
 , @dev_cod= EURonstituent @bk_cod=bk11 , @ISIN= EU0009658145 , @FININFO= 22
```

There seems to be some memory overwriten when "+=" has dev_cod as right operand. For some reason the right operand of += is written at the beginning of the string...

I also wondered about cout, so i tried to add some std::flush everywhere. But it did not make things better.

**EDIT**

Just so nobody asks. there is only one thread... :)

**@Angew** thanks ==> applyed dos2unix, and problem was solved.
**CLOSE**

local_fininfo is the en of line of a windows csv file. then local fininfo end up with 0D0A in my hexadecimal editor.

So there was indeed a carriage return that I could not see by printing local fininfo out alone.

Comment: Any chance one of the strings contains a `carriage-return` character?

Comment: I'm gonna check in DB, but it is very unlikely. good point though.

Comment: You should provide a full standalone testcase that people can take, compile, and see for themselves.

Comment: Also, the line from wich the overwrite starts is "hard-coded" 

    req += " , @dev_cod= ";

Comment: Also debug the length of the string. It would also unhide possible carriage returns.

Comment: @@PlasmaHH i'll try. Give me five minutes.

Comment: I'm sure there is no string memory overwritten but there is a problem with output to console.

Comment: If these strings come from input, it could be that a Windows-style file is being parsed as a Unix-style one.

Comment: I just debbugged the length. after dev_cod I indeed have 13 more characters written, so no carriage return.

Comment: @SergeyKolotienko please can you be more precise ?

Comment: damn good point angew... checking

Comment: @user2346536 Actually, if the string's length grows, it's indication there *is* a `CR`. That is only interpreted by the output to console. Can you output the string's characters as numbers (to get the ASCII values)?

Comment: SOLVED, thanks to @Angew

Comment: true I'll output everything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there's a `carriage-return` character in one of the strings, which gets interpreted during output. Perhaps a Windows-style file is being parsed as a Unix-style one somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

There's a carriage return in `local_fininfo`.

Comment: No i printed it separately. No There's a carriage return. 
I can't reproduce the problem in a separate executable... I keep trying.